# Javascript function not changing value of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I don't know if I am just overlooking a typo but I have the following two buttons on a form

```
<button id="saveAffidavit "class="btn btn-primary">Save Affidavit</button>
<button id ="submitAffidavit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Affidavit</button>
```

Then this is the Javascript

```
$('#submitAffidavit').click(function(){

    console.log("Submit Affidavit Button Clicked");

    submitAffidavit();
});

$('#saveAffidavit').click(function(){

    console.log("Save Affidavit Button Clicked");

    saveAffidavit();
});

function saveAffidavit(){
    console.log("Save Affidavit Ran");

    document.getElementById('submitType').value = 'Save';

    console.log(document.getElementById('submitType').value);

    document.getElementById("jpFormInput").submit();

}

function submitAffidavit(){

    console.log("Submit Affidavit Ran");

    document.getElementById('submitType').value = 'Submit';

    console.log(document.getElementById('submitType').value);

    document.getElementById("jpFormInput").submit();
}
```

The .click for 'submitAffidavit' seems to function and successfully calls the submitAffidavit() method.

the .click for 'saveAffidavit' does NOT seem to function at all.. but the form is still submitting when the button is clicked. I do not get any of the console messages printed out.

any ideas are appreciated. thanks

Comment: You need to cancel the button click.

Comment: You have a trailing space in the `saveAffidavit` button element id...

Comment: Default button type is "submit" so both will submit form unless you prevent it

Comment: You have an extra space at `id ="submitAffidavit"` in the button tag. That should be `id="submitAffidavit"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space after your ID name, making that id not work properly. (`"idName "`).

```js
$('#submitAffidavit').click(function() {
    console.log("Submit Affidavit Button Clicked");
    submitAffidavit();
});

$('#saveAffidavit').click(function() {
    console.log("Save Affidavit Button Clicked");
    saveAffidavit();
});

function saveAffidavit() {
    console.log("Save Affidavit Ran");
    document.getElementById('submitType').value = 'Save';
    console.log(document.getElementById('submitType').value);
    document.getElementById("jpFormInput").submit();
}

function submitAffidavit() {
    console.log("Submit Affidavit Ran");
    document.getElementById('submitType').value = 'Submit';
    console.log(document.getElementById('submitType').value);
    document.getElementById("jpFormInput").submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="saveAffidavit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Affidavit</button><!-- removed a space here after before the " when ending the id-->
<button id ="submitAffidavit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Affidavit</button>
```

Comment: and there it is. ugh. thank you for taking the time to point out this silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The default type attribute of `<button>` is `submit`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type
So your buttons actually look like this `<button type="submit"></button>`, after defaults are applied.

Add `type="button"` attribute to your buttons to prevent submitting.